# Can the stripped down OSX save sheet be augmented with Finder functions?

Tags: macos, finder

In a normal finder window there is a rich set of functions, yet when the finder is opened in save mode a lot of those functions are locked.

Some examples:

- rename folder
- right click and create folder
- numerous other right click options
- no red close button in the top left like there is on every other window
- no move file option
- doesn't show the path along the bottom even though my Finder is configured to do so

Is there a way to give fuller access to any or all these features from an application's save sheet?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60909/discussion-on-question-by-toni-leigh-can-the-stripped-down-osx-save-sheet-be-aug).

Answer (score 2):

Guessing *why* Apple does things (technical or otherwise) is the job of quite a few Apple Pundits.

If you find that the open and save dialog boxes are incomplete or otherwise not to your liking you should investigate Finder enhancements such as [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/index.html). I don't use it myself and understand there may be an issue with it and OSX 10.11 El Capitan but I gather is is pretty popular and has been a part of the Mac since before OSX.

Comment: +1 Additional software is required like Default Folder to augment the save sheet. There's no built in functionality that anyone has described publicly on OS X 10.13 and lower for this. The save sheet is stripped down by design.